# How to Select data from two tables which are not identical on another table using WHERE condition in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, those are "**Student**" and "**User**". I want to select the first_name and Last_name from "Student" table which does not match with "Student_ID" of the user table.

```
SELECT student.student_id, 
       student.first_name, 
       student.last_name 
FROM   student, 
       USER 
WHERE  student.student_id != USER.student_id
```

Answer (score 2):

Same as `NOT IN` version but perform a little bit better. According to this: https://www.eversql.com/sql-syntax-check-validator/

```sql
SELECT
  student.student_id,
  student.first_name,
  student.last_name
FROM
  student
WHERE
  NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT
      student_id
    from
      user
    where
      user.student_id = student.student_id
  )
```

Comment: This is superior to the `NOT IN` version, because it handles `NULL` values in `user.student_id` correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this query:

```
SELECT firstname,lastname 
FROM Student 
WHERE ID NOT IN(SELECT Student_ID from User);
```